# Repeating the same formula?

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to repeat the same formula but need to store variables every second. What I did was put all my variables in an excel file and have a reader go through the list. When I try to use the new variable, I'm only able to use it one at a time, not the whole list. 
What I would like to do is basically print y1 = 1, y2 = 2, y3 = 3
Below is an example :

```
csv file : 
column1, column2, column3 
apple, 1 , appleweight
orange, 2, orangeweight
banana, 3, bananaweight

import csv 
with open(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Untitled.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        x = row['column1']
        y = row['column2']
        z = row['column3']
        x = method.get_value(y)

        z = x.get_name()
        print (y) 
        time.sleep(1)
```

The above code, will print:

```
1
2
3
```

I would like to print

```
y1 = 1 
y2 = 2
y3 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter to iteration of the rows, and use that to print what you want.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Untitled.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        y = row['column2']
        print(f'y{i} = {y}') 
        time.sleep(1)
```